# MySQL - Like and Not Like on same column issue

Tags: mysql, sql-like

When I try to do the following in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM animal_crossing_new_horizons.item
WHERE
`source` like '%nook''s cranny%' and
`source` not like '%tree%'
ORDER BY item.name, item.variant_id, item.sort_order
```

I get the correct results where I can properly filter out rows that contains "Nook's Cranny; Apple Tree" in the "source" column (it does not appear in the results), but I still see "Nook's Cranny" values as intended.

However, when I use this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM animal_crossing_new_horizons.item
WHERE
`source` like '%nook miles%' or
`source` like '%nook shopping%' or
`source` like '%saharah%' or
`source` like '%kicks%' or
`source` like '%nook''s cranny%' or
`source` like '%able sisters%' or
`source` like '%crafting%' or
`source` like '%k.k. concert%' or
`source` like '%redd%' or
`source` like '%flick%' or
`source` like '%c.j.%' or
`source` like '%celeste%' or
`source` like '%hpp apparel shop%' or
`source` like '%assessing fossils%' or
`source` like '%cooking%' or
`source` like '%high friendship%' or
`source` like '%dig spot%' or
`source` like '%label%' or
`source` like '%pavé%' or
`source` like '%gulliver%' or
`source` like '%gullivarrr%' or
`source` like '%pascal%' or
`source` like '%brewster%' or
`source` like '%zipper%' or
`source` like '%cyrus%' or
`source` like '%harvey%' or
`source` like '%rover%' or
`source` like '%jack%' or
`source` like '%franklin%' or
`source` like '%jingle%' or
`source` like '%blathers%' or
`source` like '%nooklink%' or
`source` like '%donating%' or
`source` like '%birthday%' or
`source` like '%isabelle%' or
`source` like '%lottie%' or
`source` like '%Starting items%' or
`source` like '%Dodo Airlines%' or
`source` like '%Group Stretching%' or
`source` like '%Nintendo%' or
`source` like '%Wilbur%' or
`source` like '%Kapp''n%' or
`source` like '%HHA%' or
`source` like '%Check Toy Day stockings the day after Toy Day%' or
`source` like '%Luna%' or
`source` like '%Katrina''s Cleansing Service%' or
`source` like '%Mom%' or
`source` like '%Tom Nook%' or
`source` like '%Niko%' or
`source` like '%Recycle box%' or
`source` like '%All villagers%' or
`source` like '%Wardell%' or
`source` like '%Cyrus%' or
`source` like '%May Day Tour%' and
`source` not like '%tree%' and
`item_category` not like '%recipes%' and
`item_category` not like '%construction%' and
`item_category` not like '%reactions%' and
`item_category` not like '%achievements%'
ORDER BY item.name, item.variant_id, item.sort_order
```

Everything after the "AND" seems to not work and not be taken into account, for instance, the filtered out value using the previous request "Nook's Cranny; Apple Tree" will now appear in the results in the "source" column, along with "Recipes", "Construction", "Reactions" and "Achievements" values in the "item_category" column.

Please note that values in "item_category" are single words.

I do not completely understand why the first SELECT works correctly and the second one behaves differently, what am I missing please?

May you help me out filter out the values in the "AND" clauses on the second SELECT as well?

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should add `(` `)` to clarify the meaning?

Comment: `AND` and `OR` have different priority. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 0):

I was testing the following while @IT goldman added a comment and thank you for the suggestion.

Here is the working code:

```
SELECT *
FROM animal_crossing_new_horizons.item
WHERE
(`source` like '%nook miles%' or
`source` like '%nook shopping%' or
`source` like '%saharah%' or
`source` like '%kicks%' or
`source` like '%nook''s cranny%' or
`source` like '%able sisters%' or
`source` like '%crafting%' or
`source` like '%k.k. concert%' or
`source` like '%redd%' or
`source` like '%flick%' or
`source` like '%c.j.%' or
`source` like '%celeste%' or
`source` like '%hpp apparel shop%' or
`source` like '%assessing fossils%' or
`source` like '%cooking%' or
`source` like '%high friendship%' or
`source` like '%dig spot%' or
`source` like '%label%' or
`source` like '%pavé%' or
`source` like '%gulliver%' or
`source` like '%gullivarrr%' or
`source` like '%pascal%' or
`source` like '%brewster%' or
`source` like '%zipper%' or
`source` like '%cyrus%' or
`source` like '%harvey%' or
`source` like '%rover%' or
`source` like '%jack%' or
`source` like '%franklin%' or
`source` like '%jingle%' or
`source` like '%blathers%' or
`source` like '%nooklink%' or
`source` like '%donating%' or
`source` like '%birthday%' or
`source` like '%isabelle%' or
`source` like '%lottie%' or
`source` like '%Starting items%' or
`source` like '%Dodo Airlines%' or
`source` like '%Group Stretching%' or
`source` like '%Nintendo%' or
`source` like '%Wilbur%' or
`source` like '%Kapp''n%' or
`source` like '%HHA%' or
`source` like '%Check Toy Day stockings the day after Toy Day%' or
`source` like '%Luna%' or
`source` like '%Katrina''s Cleansing Service%' or
`source` like '%Mom%' or
`source` like '%Tom Nook%' or
`source` like '%Niko%' or
`source` like '%Recycle box%' or
`source` like '%All villagers%' or
`source` like '%Wardell%' or
`source` like '%Cyrus%' or
`source` like '%May Day Tour%')
AND NOT
(`source` like '%tree%' or
`item_category` like '%recipes%' or
`item_category` like '%construction%' or
`item_category` like '%reactions%' or
`item_category` like '%achievements%'
)
ORDER BY item.name, item.variant_id, item.sort_order
```